# Background task is terminated next time app launches

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

I am playing with [the Background Task code sample (c#) from MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Task-Sample-9209ade9). I modified the code a little bit to make it run longer, so that I can see if the application can get "re-attached" to the background task next time it is launched. My test shows that the background task always gets terminated when the application is launched for a second time. Here is the test detail:

The background task is trigger by a `SystemTrigger` of type `SystemTriggerType.TimeZoneChange`, and it works as expected if:

1. I launch the application first and then change my TimeZone setting;
2. I change my TimeZone first and then launch the application;

But if I close the application (by ALT+F4) and then launch it again before the background task completes. I will ALWAYS see that the background task is terminated. Sometimes I see messages like "`The program '[920] backgroundTaskHost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 1 (0x1).`" in the Output window.

Why is the background task terminated every time the application is launched again? Is it the design? Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

That is the project reference problem.

> If you exited program with `code 1 (0x1)` when you run backgrond task, you should add the background task project into the referece of original project.

[[Windows 8] The crash problem  about BackgroundTask](http://kukhyun.tistory.com/19) shows you how to resolve the reference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But my program's problem is the baskground task cannot get attached to the application after I close the app and restart it again. It works nicely when the app is launched for the first time. If, on the other hand, I didn't reference the task project, I think the app will crash even if I launch it for the first time.
I starts to get the feeling that this is probably "by-design".

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating the BackgroundTask in C#, and using the Windows 8 RP, I think you may have to set the output type of the project to `WinMD` file and not class library. Are you using WinMD as the output type?

Comment: Yes, I did. I guess if I don't, it's not going to work in any case.

Comment: Because I have some problems with the answer above I want to add that you have to create Windows Runtime Component.

Comment: @SzymonSasin: It was a long ago that I asked the question, when I was still using the 'previous' version of W8 PREVIEW. Now W8 RTM is avaiable but I haven't tried it on the new OS version. Not sure if the issue is still there... However, by 'you have to create Windows Runtime Component', did you mean I need to create Windows Runtime Component for the background tasks? But isn't that what the MSDN example does by default?