# Windows 8.1 background task terminated when application is launched

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, background-process

I'm encountering a strange issue when a background task is executing then the user launches the foreground application. If the user launches the app while the background task is executing, the background task is terminated. Is this normal or expected behavior?

The background task begins and ends with success in the following scenarios:

1. The foreground app is currently running
2. The foreground app is not running

I've read the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175929/background-task-is-terminated-next-time-app-launches) as it seems to be the exact issue I'm experiencing. However, the responses don't apply since I already have a reference to the background task project. This is required for a background task to even work and be registered.

### Update 3/16/2014

I've discovered that this may be more edge case than I originally anticipated. In the following scenario the application is launched successfully and the background task is not terminated.

1. Fresh boot of machine
2. Background task is manually triggered (currently triggered by InternetAvailable)
3. Launch Application

What I've discovered is that when the following steps are run the background task will terminate upon application launch

1. Launch application
2. Manually close application
3. Trigger background task
4. Launch application (application is displayed immediately as if it was suspended. Oddly enough when I run the application after closing it every other time the splash screen is always displayed. In this scenario when the background task is triggered the application seems to be in a suspended state)
5. Manually close application
6. Launch application

Again, I understand this is a very odd set of steps to reproduce this issue but if anybody is running across this or it is an expected behavior please let me know.

Thanks in advance.